# SOAP - Must specify a type attribute value for the element

Tags: python, xml, soap, salesforce, zeep

Using [Python zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/index.html), I'm interacting with Salesforce's SOAP (specifically, Metadata) API.

Trying to `createMetadata` I get this error:

`Fault: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element`

I've gathered that this is not about parameters passed to the method (the way `createMetadata` requires a `metadata` argument, which itself is an object with a `fullName` field), but rather about a missing `xsi:type` attribute somewhere.

This is my `zeep` call:

```
resp = service['createMetadata'](_soapheaders=soap_headers,
                                 metadata=[{'fullName': 'SomeCustomObject'}])
```

This is the generated XML:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:createMetadata xmlns:ns0="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <ns0:metadata>
        <ns0:fullName>SomeCustomObject</ns0:fullName>
      </ns0:metadata>
    </ns0:createMetadata>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

My question is: how can I set that `xsi:type` on whatever it needs to be set on (that `ns0:metadata` guy?) using `zeep`?

UPDATE:
Instead of using a dictionary to represent the metadata object, I replaced it with this:

```
metadata_type = client.get_type('{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}Metadata')
metadata = metadata_type(fullName='SomeCustomObject')
resp = service['createMetadata'](_soapheaders=soap_headers, metadata=[metadata])
```

The new generated XML is:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:createMetadata xmlns:ns0="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <ns0:metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns0:Metadata">
        <ns0:fullName>SomeCustomObject</ns0:fullName>
      </ns0:metadata>
    </ns0:createMetadata>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

which has the `xsi:type` attribute on the `ns0:metadata` tag, but I get the same error as before. So I guess it wasn't about a missing `xsi:type`. Any ideas on what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that `xsi:type` should use `'CustomObject'` (or another appropriate type) instead of `'Metadata'`, which is the "parent" type, I believe. Which also then requires passing more than just `fullName`.

In `zeep` that means instead of

```
metadata_type = client.get_type('{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}Metadata')
metadata = metadata_type(fullName='SomeCustomObject')
```

I used

```
custom_object_type = client.get_type('{http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}CustomObject')
custom_object = custom_object_type(fullName='SomeCustomObject__c',
                                   label='SomeCustomObject',
                                   pluralLabel='SomeCustomObjects',
                                   nameField={'label': 'name', 'type': 'Text'},
                                   deploymentStatus='Deployed',
                                   sharingModel='ReadWrite')
```

and then finally:

```
resp = service['createMetadata'](_soapheaders=soap_headers,
                                 metadata=[custom_object])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see that **xsi** is defined in **metadata**.

```
<metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CustomField">
</metadata>
```

Comment: I don't understand. What are you suggesting?

Comment: Ah, I see. You're saying the xsi:type has to be CustomObject or CustomField, or something from the right set of accepted values, of which Metadata is not one.

Comment: I only realized what you were saying after posting my answer, but I also included the explanation (which I was not gathering initially from your brief answer), as well as example `zeep` code, to make it much more complete.